# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop Word Doc not opening on first try

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am using the following code to open a Word doc

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Document document = app.Documents.Open("MyDocFile.doc");
```

After the code runs, a MS Word process is started but I never see my document. If I run the code a second time, another process is started and this time I get prompted to open a read-only copy because it is already open. I choose read-only and the document opens. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and why the document does not open on the first run of the above code?

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  Consider app.Visible = true;

Comment: @HansPassant that worked. If you want to put this as answer, I'll mark it. I looked at a few examples and none of them had this line of code in it. Thank you.

Comment: It is a pretty bad practice to write interop code that *also* allows the user to interact with the program.  Who will win?  If it fits your need then just post the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you opening it with word for a particular reason?
If you just want to open and see the file you can do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("YourSavedFilePath");
```